# Android encryption of data

Tags: android, proguard

We are developing an application that has a requirement to use HMAC when communicating with one of our back end servers.

We are required to use an algorithm which I am confident that Proguard will obfuscate enough. The issue is that the algorithm requires some initial keys that the backend service will provide to us to use in our app.

How to secure it securely on the phone? Shared Preferences is ok but then how to get it into Shared Preferences in the first place?

Comment: Everything that is stored on the phone is not secure.

Comment: I realise and someone rooting their phone and getting access to data in Shared Preferences is ok.

Comment: Then if it's ok for you just use it.